# Green Colour of Blood in "Mankatha"

Tags: production, mankatha

In The South Indian Tamil Movie, 'Mankatha' why is the colour of blood shown to be Green in the main character's imagination?

The movie is miles far from anything related to Science Fiction or Fantasy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The green blood is to ease the violence level because they didn't want to make it a bloody mess for the kids viewing the film.

You can see that information on all over the fans and review sites for the movie, for example in the [Mankatha movie Review by Arun Guhan](http://www.ajithfans.com/media/media-news/2011/09/01/mankatha-movie-review-by-arun-guhan-fans-share/).